# comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with 12 failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have restaurants where user can make reservations. For reservations, I set my time attribute as `integer`. I then used a helper to display time selection(radio button) such as 14 to 2:00pm.

```
  def new_time(h)
    if h > 12
      (h-12).to_s + ":00 PM"
    elsif h == 12
      h.to_s + ":00 PM"
    else
      h.to_s + ":00 AM"
    end
  end
```

Reservation time options are displayed on Restaurant page:

```
<%= form_for([@restaurant, @reservation], :html => {:class => 'reserve-form'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="times">
    <% @restaurant.hours_open.each do |h| %>
      <%= f.radio_button :time, h %>
      <%= f.label "time_#{h}", new_time(h), class: "reserve" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="align">
  <%= f.label :party_size,'Please enter party size' %>
  <%= f.text_field :party_size %>
  </div>
  <div class="align">
  <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Now when reservation is done, I redirect to User Profile to display that reservation. Everything works fine on development side but after deploying to heroku, I get error "We're sorry, but something went wrong." when making a reservation and I think it has something to do with reservation time displayed on user page shown below.

When I check heroku logs this is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with 12 failed):

        <% @user.reservations.each do |reservation| %>
        <div class="user-reservation align">
        <p>Restaurant: <%= reservation.restaurant.name %></p>
        <p>Reserved Time: <%= new_time(reservation.time) %></p>
        <p>Party Size: <%= reservation.party_size %></p>
        <p>Added on: <%= reservation.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `>'
    app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `new_time'
    app/views/users/show.html.erb:19:in `block in _app_views_users_show_html_erb__1649677434053595894_70057403913200'
    app/views/users/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1649677434053595894_70057403913200'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the attribute `reservation.time` which is a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` with an integer.

If your datatype is a time, why don't use just format it with [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) ?

```
<p>Reserved Time: <%= reservation.time.strftime("%I:%M%p") %></p>
```

Comment: The datatype is not time as I had set it as integer.  This is my schema:  t.integer  "time"

Comment: well with the code provided I can't see any problem... But why don't you use a time datatype ?